# jquery on success function

Tags: php, jquery

```
$('#change-form')
   .jqTransform()
   .validate({
     submitHandler: function(form) {
       $(form).ajaxSubmit({
        url: "index.php",
        success: function(){
        $(this).addClass("done");

            }
       });
     }
    });
```

I have made form.html and given

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="change-form" onsubmit="index.php">
```

but still onsubmit it doesn't go to index.php and shows thanx meaasge on same page i.e form.html

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i want that , when i click on submit button, it should go to index.php file, but it remains on form.html and displays a message "thanx, your request has been submitted"

Answer (score 1):

The `onsubmit` attribute value is supposed to be a function, not a file name.  It can be a string containing JavaScript source, but this is not common.  In your case, JavaScript tries to execute the string `index.php` as JavaScript.  I believe this fails, and that this prevents the normal form action from running.  Remove the `onsubmit` attribute from your `form` tag.

Comment: Two things you can try then: (1) See if any JavaScript errors pop up when you try to submit the form.  (2) Comment out the jQuery code that attached the submit handler and just try to do a plain HTML form submit.  Perhaps "index.php" is not in the right directory on your server?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this to move on to index.php onsubmit.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="change-form" onsubmit="here goes your function name">
```

Only function can be given in `onsubmit=""`

I think you can try this to move on to index.php onclick.

```
 onclick="location.href='index.php'"
```

Comment: my validations are through jquery

Comment: `$('#change-form')
    .jqTransform()
    .validate({
         submitHandler: function(form) {
           $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                success: function() {
                    $('#change-form').hide();
                    $('#page-wrap').append("<p class='thanks'>Thanks! Your request has been sent.</p>")
                }
           });
         }
        }); `
this is actual jquery that i was trying to modify